# MySql trigger not doing any action

Tags: php, mysql

It's probably something stupid but I'm unable to figure it out.The issue is that when i want to perform a check on **email_token** table,It's not passing.I have a simple query to update the needed data.But every time i get a false on my query.

Here is it:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER email_token_used
BEFORE INSERT
   ON email_token FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM email_token WHERE used = 'N' AND usable = 'Y' AND user_id = NEW.user_id)) THEN
        UPDATE email_token SET usable='N' WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;


END$$
```

Here is my table:
[image]

Here is the php if needed.It's working without the trigger ,the mail can't be sent since it's not updated in the table:

```
if(!password_verify($password,$output['password'])){
        self::$status = 401;
        echo "Pass 1";
      }else{
        $mail_result = self::$db->query("INSERT INTO email_token(user_id,token,created,expires,used) VALUES('{$output['user_id']}','{$token}',NOW(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'N')");
        if($mail_result){
          echo "Pass 2";
          $mailer = new Mailer();
          $mailer -> send_mail("Token authentication","Token authentication <a href='http://localhost:8888/scripts/functions/collector/login/login_step_2.php?user_id={$token}'>Link</a>",$output['email']);
        }else{
          self::$status = 409;
          echo "Error 1";
        }
      }
```

Explanation of the final goal here.
The user logs in,he/she gets a token that is being sent to their email(like a 2 stop verification system).After they get the token,they finish with the login in process.I want to prevent people from having multiple tokens,and if they login several times ,they will get the token on their email.The tokens last for 2min,and i want to update the tokens before to be not valid.

Thanks...

Comment: There's something I don't quite get. You have an `BEFORE INSERT` but using `UPDATE email_token` then an `query("INSERT INTO`. Shouldn't that be `BEFORE UPDATE` as per an example in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: In case if that exists,it should be updated.

Comment: Check for errors on it and see if something comes of it. This via php and the query.

Comment: ^ can you do that? Your `echo "Error 1";` doesn't help you here. If your code is trying to insert into something that already exists or about an AI/PK/FK issue or updating something that won't let you, then you need to check for errors. We don't know what `self::$status = 409;` does.

Comment: @Fred-ii- echo was just to see if it got to that step.Here you have a lit of REST errors :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Yeah, I started Googling that *lol* - However, that conditional seems to be falling in the `else{...}` and you need to find out why that is exactly. There isn't anything else I can add/think of, sorry. Good luck :-) I hope you get a solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run afoul of

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

I am not sure why you need a trigger here in the first place. It seems to be that you have a situation where `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UDPATE` can be used. Something like

```
INSERT INTO email_token(user_id,token,created,expires,used)
VALUES(?,?,NOW(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'N')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE usable = 'Y'
```

Note that you are using string concatenation in your queries. You should be using prepared statements instead.

Based on your comments. It sounds like all you need is a simple INSERT statement (The record needs to be inserted every time). Preceded by an UPDATE statement

```
 UPDATE email_token SET usable='N' WHERE user_id = ?
 INSERT INTO email_token(user_id,token,created,expires,used)
 VALUES(?,?,NOW(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'N')
```

First one invalidates existing records. Second one creates a new record. Still no need for a trigger.

Comment: If the user has logged in ,and if he has some tokens that are not used but the time is not expired i want to update them.But in the case if the user has no tokens that can be updated than nothing needs to be changed.And ON DUPLICATE KEY can't help here.My issue is that my trigger is not pefforming anything :D

Comment: In other words you don't need to insert any records at all?

Comment: No!The record needs to be inserted every time,but if the user has tokens that are still valide,those tokens need to be updated to be not valid.

Comment: Please never ever use the term not working here. Explain what exactly is happening. post a SHOW CREATE TABLE, add some sample data and show your updated code

Comment: When i separet update and insert it's working,but it's not when i do it your way.Also a quetions,I'm not getting errors on this.How can i check it in detail.I'm on phpmyadmin...

Comment: Glad it did. All the best with your project

Comment: Thank you :D @e4c5

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER email_token_used
BEFORE INSERT
  ON email_token FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM email_token WHERE used = 'N' AND usable = 'Y' AND user_id = NEW.user_id)) THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE email_token SET usable='N' WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
END;
END IF;


END$$
```

Comment: The question deserves a (better) explanation, IMHO. *"Try this"* doesn't "explain" much.

Comment: I thought that it missed the BEGIN <statement> END; block.